# Cordova Android - stay on background on resume?

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

My app uses custom url scheme plugin, all works fine: my app is launched and when I type `myappurl://` in Firefox address bar, Firefox loses focus and my app is activated.

Is it possible to have my app continue working in background and the browser keep focus when executing `myappurl://`?

I tried suspending on resume, but the browser loses focus and homescreen is activated.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to run Javascript code in background, you would need to have a service for that. [Maybe this](https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService) could help you?

Comment: In my project I'm using cordova-plugin-background-mode ( https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode ) and cordova-plugin-background-app ( https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-background-app ), but I'm thinking that the problem is in focusing app-window, not background process.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to execute while the app is in background mode?

Comment: Nothing, app is paused until it receives new request URL, for example: `myapp://turn_wifi?on` or `myapp://turn_wifi?off` ... No hard code required.

Answer (score 0):

When you resume Cordova recreate the CordovaWebView. I think do you need to use a plugin.

Comment: I'm using Crosswalk, my test timer (`setInterval()`) work perfectly in background and if I resume app.

Comment: Probably but in background you can't access to webview. And when you resume a new webview is created.